# Simple less file that does not work in dotless

Tags: css, less, dotless

The following less works in less.js but not in dotless. Can that be true?

```
#my-btn > .silver {  
color: blue;  
}

&:hover, &.hover {
 #my-btn > .silver;
}
```

Comment: What is the & supposed to do, when the rule is not inside another rule?

Comment: What is main problem you are facing?? Have you tried anything for that?

Comment: The & in the example are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Already found an answer: 
https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/144.
It's by design I guess.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer: Yes, it can be True.

I'll assume in answer to Guffa's comment that your `&` is contained in a parent selector block; if not, that could be your problem.

Nevertheless, whether that is your problem or not, I have noticed compiler differences for LESS, where some allow certain things and not others. One of the things I have noticed is that some compilers allow for a compound selector string to be a mixin (like your `#my-btn > .silver`), whereas others only seem to allow singular selectors for mixins (like `#my-btn` *or* `.silver`).

I could not tell you which compilers allow what combination of selectors, but if it is working in less.js and not dotless, then that is probably why. Whether this is a bug in dotless or a feature difference in the compilers is probably a matter of debate.